# NGINX: check whether $remote_user equals to the first part of the location

Tags: regex, nginx, elasticsearch

I can't figure out how to configure the check whether `$remote_user` equals to the first part of the `location`.

```
location / {
  auth_basic "ElasticSearch";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/search_passwords;

  location ~/([^/]*)/ { # named capture did not work either
    if ($remote_user = $1) { # ERROR: Unknown variable: $1 / $NAMEDWHATEVER
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

My use-case:

I am trying to "secure" an ElasticSearch-Cluster by using a nginx-reverse proxy for authentication. I want to allow multiple users, but the modifications for a new user should be as simple as possible; best case - just change the htpasswd-file.

I'm trying to adopt the [nginx-elasticsearch-proxy](https://gist.github.com/karmi/986390) but fail to check whether `remote_name` and `index-name` are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible and you can also define a name of a variable when matching with regex.

Here in the code fragment below, I assign the result of the regex to the variable **$username**. Then I can check it and if matching the **$remote_user** (be sure that this one is correctly set, in case just debug it as I did) then I added an extra header to the response so you can see it with the `Firebug network console` or just by using the `curl` command .

Have a look to see if this one helps you.

```
location / {
  auth_basic "ElasticSearch";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/search_passwords;

  location ~ /(?<username>([^/]*))/ { # capture and store in the username variable
    if ($remote_user = $username ) { 
      add_header 'matched' 'true $username'; 
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

See also this [How to I get variables from location in nginx?](https://superuser.com/questions/330194/how-to-i-get-variables-from-location-in-nginx) for more info.